# P2 italian math olympiad 2019

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, contest-math

> Show that if $p + q^2$ is a perfex square then $p^2+q^n$ isn't a perfec square for all $n$ natural number, wher $p,q$ are prime number

**My solution**

$p+q^2=x^2 \Longleftrightarrow p=(x-q)(x+q)\Longleftrightarrow x-q=1$, because p is prime. So we have:

$x-q=1$               $(1)$

$x+q=p$               $(2)$

Now suppose the for some integer $l$ we have

$p^2 + q^n = l^2 \Longleftrightarrow q^n=(l-p)(p+l)$. Suppose $q$ odd then if $(l-p)\neq 1$, we must have $q|(l-p),(l+p) $ (because $(l-p)(l+p)$ is a power of q) and so we have $l \equiv p \equiv (-l) (mod$ $ q)$, that is a contraddiction for odd number. So $q$ odd implies $l-p=1$.
So $q^n= p+l=2p+1\equiv 3 \equiv 0 (mod $ $q)$ because $p \equiv x (mod $ $ q)$ for $(2)$ that is $1 (mod $ $ q)$ for $(1)$. So $q= 3$ if $q$ odd prime because $3 \equiv 0 (mod q)$. If q even implies $q=2$. For $q=3$, $p=7$ for $(2)$ and $(1)$. So $7^2 + 3^n =l^2 \Longleftrightarrow 3^n= (l-7)(l+7)$ that has no solution modulo $3$. For $q=2$ we have $2^n = (l-5)(l+5)$ that has no solution modulo 4. So there are no no solution.

This solution is different from official solution. Can someone tell me if there are any errors or if it is correct?

Comment: There is $p^2+q^n$ in your solution, but $p+q^n$ in the statement. Is the $^2$ missing?

Comment: Yes I do a mistake to write the text of exercise and $^2$ is missing

Comment: @NDB I have edited the error, thanks to say it to me

Comment: The start of your proof is good, but your last paragraph in your solution reads like word-salad, I have to say [sorry].

Comment: @Mike, I write a little well, I am sorry but is quiete hard fo rme write in English

Comment: if there are some unclear things you can write them in comments. You can write also the errors (if there are) in comment.